# Scalatest: have a test which is valid if one of both matchers matches

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest

I am having a hard time having an `or` relation between to matchers on an case class which match on different methods/fields of given class.

I know I could do it with `exists` an `||` which would end up with a `Bool` but will erase all Feedback from the testing Framework which I do not want.

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
class ExampleSpec extends FunSpec with Matchers {

  case class Element(count: Int,  value: String)

  val data : List[Element] = List(
    Element(0, "ok"),
    Element(5, "")
    Element(0,""),
    Element(1, "a")
  )

  describe("My data test") {
    data foreach {d =>
        it("valid data either has a count > 0 or the value is not empty") {
          d.count should be > 0 or d.value should not be empty // I have no idea how to get the or working
        }

    }
  }
}
```

The best thing I could come up with was:

```
   def okishSolution(e: Element) = {
     val res = (e.count > 0 || d.value.nonEmpty)
     if (! res) { info(s"Failed: $d , did not meet requirements") }

      res should be(true)
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the docs on and/or? http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#logicalExpressions

Comment: Yes, because this case is not documented there I am asking this question.

Comment: I see what you mean. They've been responsive to github tickets before, maybe file one. You can probably accomplish this with a custom combinator.

Comment: Ticket opened: https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfect but you could use `should matchPattern`

```
d should matchPattern {
  case x:Element if x.count > 0 =>
  case x:Element if x.value != "" =>
}
```